# подскажите, создать программу для определения количества целых чисел между числами Z и X

Tags: c

подскажите, создать программу для определения количества целых чисел между числами Z и X.Создайте программу для определения
количества целых чисел, которые находятся
между числами Z и Х. Значение числа
Z и Х вводится с клавиатуры: Z = 2,
X = 50.

Comment: Как очевидно: n = x - z -1;

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    int X, Z;
    scanf(%d %d",&Z,&X);
    printf("%d\n", (Z < X)? X-Z+1 : Z-X+1);
    }
```

Это если числа вводить. Но я не понимаю, как понять ваше - что числа вводятся с клавиатуры, и при этом точно равны 2 и 50? А если пользоватиель введет что-то другое?